# IE8 & Respond.js - Included Dynamic CSS Not Applying

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I'm having some trouble with IE8 recognising some CSS that is generated from a PHP file and then included in my sites header. This CSS works perfectly in all other browsers I've tested but it simply won't apply in IE8.

If I move the dynamic CSS into my main css files - it works fine.

By dynamic, I mean the the CSS is generated from PHP. I'm already using respond.js to enable media queries in IE8 which is working because if I put this CSS in my main file - the CSS works.

**However,** if I put non-media query styles in the same file - it does apply. So this must be an issue with respond.js not seeing that responsive CSS.

When I 'View Source' the file has definitely included as it's printed in there but for some reason IE8 won't apply the styles. It doesn't show in Developer Tools.

Basically, the CSS should display a black menu bar at the top of the page when the browser window is narrower than 782 pixels.

You can see the full thing at: http://sandbox.benpalmer.me/flow/test/

The head of my document looks like this (this is a Wordpress theme/template):

```
<!doctype html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7 <?php if($theme_settings['modernizr-version'] != 'none'): echo 'no-js'; endif; ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 <?php if($theme_settings['modernizr-version'] != 'none'): echo 'no-js'; endif; ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 <?php if($theme_settings['modernizr-version'] != 'none'): echo 'no-js'; endif; ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie10 <?php if($theme_settings['modernizr-version'] != 'none'): echo 'no-js'; endif; ?>"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class="<?php if($theme_settings['modernizr-version'] != 'none'): echo 'no-js'; endif; ?>"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>

<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ) . bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <?php

wp_head();

include(locate_template('assets/css/dynamic.css.php')); ?>

<!--[if lt IE 9]> <?php
    if($theme_settings['modernizr-version'] == 'none'): ?><script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/js/vendor/modernizr.min.js"></script><?php endif; ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/js/vendor/selectivzr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/assets/js/vendor/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

The `include(locate_template('assets/css/dynamic.css.php'));` file that is being included is set up like this:

```
<?php

/*
| --------------------------------------------------------------------
| Primary Navigation
| --------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/* Breakpoint
| -------------------------------------------------------------------- */ ?>

<style type="text/css">

@media all and (max-width: <?php echo get_theme_mod('nav-primary-breakpoint', '782px'); ?>) {

    #wrapper {
        margin-top: 42px;
    }

    .admin-bar #wrapper {
        margin-top: 88px;
    }

    #mobile-header {
        display: block;
    }

    #menu-primary {
        display: none;
    }

    .drawer {
        margin-top: 42px;
        padding-top: 42px;
        top: -42px;
    }

}
</style>
```

This one has me stumped - I've been Googling for an hour which brought up suggestions of changing my DOCTYPE, making sure my comments are ended properly etc but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that by "dynamic CSS" you mean [CSS media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/). If so, the answer is very simple:

> IE8 does not support media queries.

There are some JS polyfills that solve the issue, the most famous one is perhaps [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).

### EDIT

From the discussion in comments: It seems that the issue is caused by the fact, that Respond.js **can read CSS from linked stylesheets only**, not from inlined CSS.

Comment: Apologies for any confusion - by dynamic I mean it is generated from PHP. I've updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: 0Neji, correct me if I'm wrong, but the dynamic CSS you include by `include(locate_template)` consists of media query only, right? So it would work anywhere BUT IE8 and lower.

Comment: See my edit to main post - I'm using respond.js to enable media query. If I put a non-media query style in there though it does work which points me towards an issue with respond.js.

Comment: I see, sorry for my lack of attention. If you use **respond.js**, you need to include it BEFORE the CSS you need to affect.

Comment: Also it is also advised to always include your scripts by [properly hooked `wp_enqueue_script` function](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-load-scripts-in-wordpress-themes/) and add `wp_head` hook right before the end of `<head>` tag.

Comment: I've tried it before my CSS but that conflicts with the authors instructions and also doesn't work. Most of my scripts are enqueued but this being a PHP file (that needs access to WP functions) that's not possible. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I see, Respond.js should really be included AFTER the CSS ... Another guess than - I browsed [the respond.js file](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/src/respond.js) on their GitHub a little and although Javascript is not my strongest suit, it seems that media queries **get recognized from linked stylesheets only**, not from inline CSS. But as you've posted the issue to their forum on GitHub, I think they will clarify it themselves ...

Comment: Yea, I think that's it. css3-media-queries.js also has the same issue so I think I may be out of luck on this one.